# Angular Custom Elements, Constructor vs ngDoBootstrap

Tags: javascript, angular, custom-element

Is there a difference between creating and defining the custom elements in the `constructor` and `ngDoBootstrap` function?
I saw both ways but I can not determine what is the best approaches and the differences between them.

```
const helloWolrd = createCustomElement(HelloWolrdComponent, { injector: injector });
customElements.define('hello-world', helloWolrd );
```